# Flex button or any control with two labels

Tags: apache-flex, button

How can I have two labels on a Flex button, one label on top and another on the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<mx:VBox verticalGap="0"  x="60" y="107">
    <mx:Canvas cornerRadius="5" backgroundColor="0xff0000" backgroundAlpha=".5" borderStyle="solid">
        <mx:Label text="Step 1" fontSize="20" fontStyle="italic" fontWeight="bold" width="171" />
    </mx:Canvas>
    <mx:Canvas cornerRadius="5" backgroundColor="0xff0000" backgroundAlpha=".5" borderStyle="solid">
        <mx:Label text="Initial Request" fontSize="20" fontStyle="italic" fontWeight="bold" width="100%" />
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:VBox>
```

This is not the correct solution, but you can make a Canvas feel like button if you want. Flexlib has a component where they provide solution for Multiline Label.

Answer (score 2):

With a Spark architecture button, you should just be able to create a custom button skin.

If you're using the Halo/MX architecture, then you'll have to extend the component.  IF you google for [multilabel button](http://www.google.com/search?q=Flex+multilabel+Button&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a), a bunch of solutions come up.

Comment: @Brian Good catch.  I'm losing myself in the Spark architecture, where the RadioButton is an actual button.  I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Flextras can you just give me an insight on this... i mean Spark Arch button... any examples out there

Answer (score 1):

You can make custom skin for your button. In that skin's `Label`, set the `maxDisplayedLines` attribute to as many lines as you need.